# react-native-image-picker restarting app when gallery opens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

in my react-native I'm using react-native-image-picker to upload images from my gallery to my backend.

Problem is each time gallery opens to select a photo my app restarts for no reason.

I found some GitHub issues that mention this issue but it seems no solution has been found.

https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/1941

https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/1460

[React native image picker causes application to restart without error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64769576/react-native-image-picker-causes-application-to-restart-without-error)

Do you guys have any idea how can I avoid app restarting and fetching on startup data?

Comment: Doesn't the third answer you added in your question answer your question?

Comment: It doesnt fix anything since I have to select image from gallery